# Running multiple horizontals scrolls on one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have found an excellent example of what I need for scrolling a div on my page:-

Codepen - https://codepen.io/zheisey/pen/xxGbEOx

However, I want to allow for multiple divs to be able to scroll with this functionality. Could you please advise?

I tried this by adding '.scrolling-wrapper2', but the scroll is not working on my second wrapper.

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.scrolling-wrapper, .scrolling-wrapper2');
```

Full code below -

```
  <div class="scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div>
  </div>

  <div class="scrolling-wrapper scrolling-wrapper2">
  <div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div><div class="card"><h2>Plain Text</h2></div>
  </div>

<style>
.scrolling-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  cursor: grab;
}

.scrolling-wrapper.active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.scrolling-wrapper[data-dragging="true"] a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.card {
  color: white;
  background-color: tomato;
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* Centering text only */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>

<script>
const slider = document.querySelector('.scrolling-wrapper, .scrolling-wrapper2');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  let rect = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  // Get initial mouse position
  startX = e.pageX - rect.left;
  // Get initial scroll position in pixels from left
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  console.log(startX, scrollLeft);
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.dataset.dragging = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});

slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.dataset.dragging = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  let rect = slider.getBoundingClientRect();
  e.preventDefault();
  slider.dataset.dragging = true;
  // Get new mouse position
  const x = e.pageX - rect.left;
  // Get distance mouse has moved (new mouse position minus initial mouse position)
  const walk = (x - startX);
  // Update scroll position of slider from left (amount mouse has moved minus initial scroll position)
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  console.log(x, walk, slider.scrollLeft);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```sh
  <div class="scrolling-wrapper2">
```

with

```sh
  <div class="scrolling-wrapper2 scrolling-wrapper">
```

Actually, you don't need to create new class for second `<div>` but if you are creating, you have not provided resepective `CSS` to it.

Comment: thanks for the comment but the second scroll is still not working

Comment: I guess its working fine, have a look here: https://codepen.io/sinhapaurush/pen/GRmXjOO

Comment: hi no thats not working, the second slider does not work

Comment: Hmm, do you want autoscroll functionality or something else? I guess its working as same in comparision to first scroll.

Comment: so first scroll you can click the middle element and drag left and right, but on second scroll you cant do this